# "No bluetooth adapters found" error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, bluetooth

I use **HP Pavilion g6-2304tx**. Initially it came with Windows 8. Then I uninstalled Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Bluetooth was turned off while removing Windows 8. Now I am not able to use bluetooth. When I open "Bluetooth", a message "**No bluetooth adapters found**" is shown. Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try installing bluetooth manager from the ubuntu software center - no guarantee. worked for someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows on the same PC configure your Blutooth software to operate in windows generic usb (Google to set up) their own software pre=installed. Your mouse and keyboard should automatically work when you switch to Ubuntu...mine does !!